# To Feel One’s Heart Fill/Filled With?

Tags: verbs, past-participles, participles, stative-verbs

“Stephen *felt his heart filled* by Fleming’s words and did not answer.”

I read this sentence, from *Portrait of the Artist*, and wondered if the use of the past participle *filled* was an abbreviation or ellipsis of a larger construction and whether there would be much difference between the verb *fill* and participle *filled* had Joyce chosen the former instead of the latter. One describes an action, the other a state, right? But each is fine?

Answer (score 1):

Consider your stomach:  If you feel your stomach "filled" that means you've eaten enough.  If you feel your stomach "fill" that means you can sense food entering it.  A process vs an end state.

The heart, in this sense, is a little more metaphoric, but the same basic idea.